# reading a specific line from one file using a value from another

Tags: python, file, line

I have two files. One file contains lines of numbers. The other file contains lines of text. I want to look up specific lines of text from the list of numbers. Currently my code looks like this.

```
a_file = open("numbers.txt")
b_file = open("keywords.txt")

for position, line in enumerate(b_file):
    lines_to_read = [a_file]
    if position in lines_to_read:
        print(line)
```

The values in numbers look like this..

```
26
13
122
234
41
```

The values in keywords looks like (example)

```
this is an apple
this is a pear
this is a banana 
this is a pineapple
...
...
...
```

I can manually write out the values like this

```
lines_to_read = [26,13,122,234,41]
```

but that defeats the point of using a_file to look up the values in b_file. I have tried using strings and other variables but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

`[a_file]` is a list with one single element which is `a_file`. What you want is a list containing the lines which you can get with `a_file.readlines()` or `list(read_lines)`. But you do not want the text value of lines but their integer value, and you want to search often the container meaning that a set would be better. At the end, I would write:

```
lines_to_read = set(int(line) for line in a_file)
```

This is now fine:

```
for position, line in enumerate(b_file):
    if position in lines_to_read:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the contents of the `a_file` to get the numbers out.

Something like this should work:

```
lines_to_read = [int(num.strip()) for num in a_file.readlines()]
```

This will give you a list of the numbers in the file - assuming each line contains a single line number to lookup.

Also, you wouldn't need to put this *inside* the loop. It should go *outside* the loop - i.e. *before* it -- these numbers are fixed once read in from the file, so there's no need to process them again in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this...

```
a_file = open("numbers.txt")
b_file = open("keywords.txt")

keywords_file = b_file.readlines()
for x in a_file:
  print(keywords_file[int(x)-1])
```

This reads all lines of the keywords file to get the data as a list, then iterate through your numbers file to get the line numbers, and use those line numbers as the index of the array

Answer (score 0):

socal_nerdtastic helped me find this solution. Thanks so much!

```
# first, read the numbers file into a list of numbers
with open("numbers.txt") as f:
    lines_to_read = [int(line) for line in f]

# next, read the keywords file into a list of lines
with open("keywords.txt") as f:
    keyword_lines = f.read().splitlines()

# last, use one to print the other
for num in lines_to_read:
    print(keyword_lines[num])
```